# removeElement() and clear() doesn't work in doctrine 2 with array collection property

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get some simple CRUD done with doctrine 2 but when it's time to update a record with one property set as an array collection I don't seem to get removeElement() to work as it's supposed to. I even tried doing it in this ridiculously ugly way:

```
foreach($entity->getCountries() as $c) {
        $entity->getCountries()->removeElement($c);
        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
}
```

and it didn't work... Anyone knows how to handle this? I've asked for a solution to this in many different forms and haven't got a good response so far... seems there's lack of good examples of Doctrine 2 CRUD handling. I'll post more code at request.

**Edit**

```
//in user entity
/**
 * 
 * @param \Doctring\Common\Collections\Collection $property
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Countries",mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $countries;

//in countries entity
/**
 *
 * @var User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="id") 
 * @JoinColumns({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to remove all the countries? Or are you trying to remove one country? Have you read the section on Working with Associations in the docs: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#removing-associations

Comment: yes @rojoca I've read it all. And I'm trying to remove all the countries associated to one user entity, so that I can change them for more different countries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do something similar in a project with Events which have participants not unlike your User/Country relationship. I will just lay out the process and you can see if there's anything you are doing differently.

On the `Participant` entity

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="participants", fetch="LAZY")
 * @JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable="TRUE")
 * @var Event
 */
protected $event;
```

On the `Event` entity:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Participant", mappedBy="event")
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
protected $participants;
```

Also in `Event#__constructor` I initialize like this:

```
$this->participants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

Here is how I update an event:

```
public function update(Event $event, Event $changes)
{
    // Remove participants
    $removed = array();
    foreach($event->participants as $participant)
    {
        if(!$changes->isAttending($participant->person))
        {
            $removed[] = $participant;
        }
    }

    foreach($removed as $participant)
    {
        $event->removeParticipant($participant);
        $this->em->remove($participant);
    }

    // Add new participants
    foreach($changes->participants as $participant)
    {
        if(!$event->isAttending($participant->person))
        {
            $event->addParticipant($participant);
            $this->em->perist($participant);
        }
    }

    $event->copyFrom($changes);
    $event->setUpdated();
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

The methods on the `Event` entity are:

```
public function removeParticipant(Participant $participant)
{
    $this->participants->removeElement($participant);
    $participant->unsetEvent();
}

public function addParticipant(Participant $participant)
{
    $participant->setEvent($this);
    $this->participants[] = $participant;
}
```

The methods on the `Participant` entity are:

```
public function setEvent(Event $event)
{
    $this->event = $event;
}

public function unsetEvent()
{
    $this->event = null;
}
```

**UPDATE**: isAttending method

```
/**
 * Checks if the given person is a 
 * participant of the event
 * 
 * @param Person $person
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function isAttending(Person $person)
{
    foreach($this->participants as $participant)
    {
        if($participant->person->id == $person->id)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm adapting this to my project. One quick question though... I'm passing my update function an array ($_POST actually) how do you set the event and where so that you pass it as an object? I guess that's much "healthier" for doctrine, right? is there a way to "automagically" feed the object with the array?

Comment: I would avoid "automagical" object creation from $_POST. The reason I do it like this is that the event input is complex and requires a lot of validation. I have a class (factory) that takes an array (e.g., `$_POST`) and creates an `Event` object. Once I have validated that object I can just save it if it is "new", or use it to update an existing event as above. You don't need to go to this extreme if your input is simple and only requires simple validation. Just make sure you always validate input.

Comment: with your help and example I was able to overcome my biggest problem with Doctrine 2, I was really stuck with this and now my code even looks prettier. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**New answer**

In your countries entity, should you not have:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="countries")
```

instead of inversedBy="id"?

**Initial answer**

You need to set the countries field in your entity as remove cascade. For example, on a bidirectional one to many relationship:

```
class Entity
{
    /**
     * 
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Country", mappedBy="entity", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $countries;
}
```

This way, when saving your entity, doctrine will also save changes in collections attached to your entity (such as countries). Otherwise you have to explicitly remove the countries you want to remove before flushing, e.g.

```
$this->em()->remove($aCountry);
```

This is also valid for persist, merge and detach operations. More information [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations).

Comment: @faken check the edit, it's already set as you suggested, however it doesn't work.

Comment: @faken well I tried that too and I still don't seem to get these damn countries to be removed

Comment: I think you have to recreate or update the schema after making these changes on the entities. Did you do that? (Beware of just "updating" the schema, it usually trashes the DB; it's probably better to delete the tables and recreate them)

Comment: yes, I did that too. It's been a pretty long and frustrating day and everything that was supposed to work hasn't worked. Do you have any CRUD examples where there's an update for a record with a OneToMany relationship? I haven't really found anything good online on that.