# Symfony BootstrapCollection with VichUploader - element remove does not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine, vichuploaderbundle

I am using the BootstrapCollection from
http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/ 
with the VichUploader
https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle

It is working fine except the delete function.
If i try to delete a child (PDF File) only the name property is empty, but not the whole row / entity will delete.

> Parent formType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'files',
            BootstrapCollectionType::class,
            [
                'type'               => NewsPdfFileType::class,
                'required'           => false,
                'allow_add'          => true,
                'allow_delete'       => true,
                'label'              => 'PDF',
                'translation_domain' => 'entities',
            ]
        );
    }
```

> Child FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'pdfFile',
                VichFileType::class,
                [
                    'required'      => false,
                    'download_link' => true,
                    'allow_delete'  => true,
                    'label'         => 'PDF'
                ]
            );

    }
```

This are my relations:

> Parent entity NewsPdf:

```
class NewsPdf
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Brightside\CMSBundle\Entity\News")
     */
    private $news;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mandant\CMSPlusBundle\Entity\NewsPdfFile", mappedBy="newsPdf", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $files;
.
.
.
.
```

> Child Entity NewsPdfFile:

```
class NewsPdfFile
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mandant\CMSPlusBundle\Entity\NewsPdf", inversedBy="files")
     * @JoinColumn(name="newsPdf_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $newsPdf;

    /**
     * @var File
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="news_pdf", fileNameProperty="pdfName")
     *
     */
    private $pdfFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $pdfName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;
.
.
.
```

> In my parent entity I already have a delete function:

```
/**
     * @param NewsPdfFile $file
     */
    public function removeFile(NewsPdfFile $file)
    {
        $this->files->removeElement($file);
    }
```

but I cant get it to work.
When I try to remove the element (in my formType there is the allow_delete option) only the "pdfName" property will be empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the soultion by myself:

[Symfony does not remove entity from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771909/symfony-does-not-remove-entity-from-collection)

I need to change my remove function in the parent entity:

```
    /**
     * @param NewsPdfFile $file
     */
    public function removeFile(NewsPdfFile $file)
    {
        $this->files->removeElement($file);
        $file->setPdfFile(null);
    }
```

and an orphanRemoval=true in OneToMany Annotation:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mandant\CMSPlusBundle\Entity\NewsPdfFile", mappedBy="newsPdf", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $files;
```